# The loading order of Js code and ajax request of Jquery in the Dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function f(){
$.post('1.php',{},function(){window.location.href="../../2.php";});
}
```

When click a button,excute the function f.The code above can run correctly and achieve the     wanted function.But when the code changes into the follow format:

```
function f(){
$.post('1.php',{},function(){});
window.location.href="../../2.php";
}
```

the ajax request will not work.I know it has something to do with the Javascript load order,but I want to make it clear in  a deep level.It is very nice of you to help me and explain it in detail.Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have

```
$.post('1.php',{},function(){});
window.location.href="../../2.php";
```

the second line is executed as soon as the first one has been executed. But the first statement only **launches** the ajax request, it doesn't **block** until the browser has really sent the whole request to the server.

As this second line replaces the page, it also stops the script and tells the browser it can stop what it was being doing for the page, like querying a server.

The solution is what you have in your first code :

```
$.post('1.php',{},function(){window.location.href="../../2.php";});
```

the `window.location` change is only done when the browser has received the answer.

Comment: I think I have got the point,but there is still some puzzle.In my case the server insert some date into the datebase after the ajax request was sent,but in the second code segment there is nothing in my db,that is to say the server doesn't response the request.

Comment: So back to the ansewer above,does it because the browser has not sent the request out yet when the window.loaction excutes?For in my opinion,if the request was sent out ,the db should be inserted in some date.Hope for your reply.

Comment: The script asks the browser to send, which isn't instantaneous and happens in another browser thread, then just after tells the browser to stop everything. Nothing has probably even be done for the querying.

Comment: Aha,I see,it explains the matter.Thank you very much!